# Reduce Significant Figures in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

**Rules:**

I want to reduce every cell to at most 4 decimals after the decimal point and keep all whole numbers the same and keep all integers as integers . If a number is a whole number like 323, I want it to stay as 323. Additionally if a number is already 323.000 I want to make it 323. I don't want any thing such as 323.0000 which is stored as a double. If a number is 3567.31415926535 I want it to become 3567.3142.

How do I do this so that my entire spreadsheet is formatted this way?

Comment: Do you just want to change the display of the numbers or their actual values? If the format I believe a custom number format like `#.####` should do the job

Comment: I'm not sure, I just want it so that when I make a fancy table, 323 isn't 323.000 and 3.1415926 is 3.1416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text() function with if().

Eg : `=TEXT(A1,IF(A1-INT(A1)=0,"0","#.####"))`

If it works, give it a tick. If it's not, share the error and we can troubleshoot it again. ( :

Comment: I already have filled out cells in Excel. How do I apply the text function with if() onto those cells directly without needing to copy and paste?

Comment: Without using VBA.. I don't know.. sorry. || On the other hand..  ( just a suggestion ) If it was up to me, I'd use one sheet for data entry table, and another (with this formula) as the reported/output table. Both with exactly the same table headings. /(^_^)>